# ¿Porque el mensaje de AlertDialog se muestra en otro menú?

Tags: android, alertdialog

tengo creado un menú horizontal, con varios elementos, pongamos como ejemplo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la última opción de este menú “MENU 4” tengo puesto un código para comprobar si el GPS está activado; Si entro directamente a esta actividad y el GPS está apagado, me muestra un mensaje para que lo active, hasta aquí todo bien

Lo malo es que, si entro directamente a la opción anterior de ese menú “MENU 3”, también muestra ese mensaje si el GPS esta desactivado.

¿Porque salta ese mensaje en el menú anterior si no tengo puesto ningún código para comprobar si el GPS?

código utilizado

**MainActivity**

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Menu1();
            case 1:
                return new Menu2();
            case 2:
                return new Menu3();
            case 3:
                return new Menu4();
            default:
                return new Menu1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
   }
```

**Menu 4**

```
Fragment fragment = null;
....
....
if (fragment instanceof Menu4){
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
     AlertNoGps();
}
        }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que pongas tu código, porque posiblemente lo estés usando en background o de otra forma que tus demás activitys lo usan.

Comment: @Gerard_jcr ya lo he puesto, no lo puse antes porque el código en su actividad funciona bien, pensé que no tenia nada que ver con el código que muestra la alerta.

Comment: podrías poner el código donde seleccionas un activity u otra.

Comment: ya esta puesto, son las opciones que tiene el menú, no se si es ese el que dices.

Comment: pues hombre, realmente no son activitys distintos .. estas usando fragment .. que heredan métodos de un padre. posiblemente esto te esta sucediendo, la manera rápida de averiguarlo es usando el debbug .. pon un punto de interrupción en tu método y cambia de un menú  a otro.. te darás cuenta que entra a tu método  en todos

Comment: El debbug es desesperante, desde que actualice android studio cuando pongo un punto de interrupción, si que se para en ese punto, pero antes y despues se para tambien en todas las lineas de código que tiene android studio, no se como solucionar eso para que solo se pare donde yo diga, y sobre lo que dices de que entra en todos los métodos, cuando pulso en el `Menú 3` entra también en el `Menú 4` y muestra el mensaje, pero si entro en  el `Menú 2`no entra en el `Menú 4`, y claro, no muestra el mensaje, no se porque y como evitar que no entre en el ultimo.

Comment: a simple vista el problema se debe a la herencia de usar frangment. si quieres una solución rápida .. te diría que identifiques el frangment donde quieres que aparezca el mensaje y en tu código añades la condición.. si estas en el fragmente correcto muestra .. caso contrario no hace nada.   no es la solución correcta a tu problema pero no te puedo ayudar mas  sin tener mas detalles de tu código.

Comment: Que código es el que necesitas? he quitado el código que detecta si esta o no activado el gps para que no muestre el mensaje, y aun así, cuando pulso en el `Menú 3` para entrar a ese menú, no se porque antes tiene que entrar en el `Menú 4" ( ͡ʘ ͜ʖ ͡ʘ) 

Comment: @Gerard_jcr he cambiado el código para intentar poner la condición y ver si estoy en el fragment que se pulso en el menú, pero ahora no me muestra nada, ni entrando directamente al menú 4.

Comment: que interesante, sin poder ver  el código se me hace un poco difícil ayudarte, por la tarde / noche haré un ejemplo y  lo compartiré.. así podremos comparar y llegar a una solución.

Comment: El código es el que he puesto en el primero post, con el compruebo si el gps está activo, los menús que hay en el **MainActivity** extienden de Fragment, en todos muestro una serie de botones, en el **menú 4** tengo puesto dos botones **menu4a** y **menu4b** que abren otro Fragment que contiene coordenadas para escoger, ese código lo he puesto en los **menú 4a** y no salta cuando se pulsa en el menú 3, pero me gustaría hacer la comprobación en el menú 4